# ¿En qué consisten las relaciones en SQL: Uno a uno, uno a varios, varios a varios?

Tags: sql, álgebra-relacional

Cuando estamos diseñando nuestras bases de datos y hay que crear relaciones entre tablas nos solemos encontrar con este dilema:

¿Qué tipo de relación debo establecer entre ambas tablas?

- Relación *uno a uno*
- Relación *uno a varios*
- Relación *varios a varios*

En algunos casos la respuesta es evidente, en otros podría ser ambigua, y en otros no es para nada evidente.

¿En qué consisten estos tres tipos de relaciones? Una respuesta a esta pregunta, ayudaría mejor a decidir qué tipo de relación usar en los casos generales.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62415/discussion-on-question-by-a-cedano-algebra-de-relaciones-en-bases-de-datos).

Answer (score 9):

**Algunos ejemplos de aplicación podrían ser:**

**Relación uno a uno:**

- Una persona solo puede tener una nariz y una nariz solo puede tener una persona.
- Un registro de población(CURP en México) sólo puede tener una persona y una persona solo puede tener una curp.

**Relación uno a varios**

- Un padre puede tener muchos hijos pero un hijo solo puede tener un padre.
- Un carro puede tener muchas llantas (En este caso se restringe uno a 4 en el caso más común) y una llanta solo puede tener un carro.
- Dependiendo del contexto en que trabajes y siendo más prácticos puedes tener que un cliente puede ser atendido solo por un vendedor pero un vendedor puede tener muchos clientes.

**Relación muchos a muchos**

- Muchos clientes pueden comprar muchos productos y muchos productos pueden ser comprados por muchos clientes.
- Muchos amigos pueden tener muchos amigos.
- En un sistema muchos usuarios pueden acceder a muchos módulos.

La idea principal es tener en cuenta primero que tipo de interacción tendremos con los datos y este dato que tipo de interacción tendrá con quien esta relacionado.

Hablando en esquemas de base de datos normalmente en un primer paso creas las identidades que necesitas, de manera sencilla sin entrar en detalles. Después aplicas las formas normales por cada uno de los niveles. Según la teoría es más que suficiente el grado 3 de normalización. Para este punto las relaciones entre las tablas son más que claras.

Algo de info sobre esto:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos#Tercera_Forma_Normal_.283FN.29

Conociendo esto y una idea yo utilizo preguntas como :

¿Cuantas veces voy a repetir un dato en la tabla?
¿Cuantas veces lo voy a llamar?
¿A quien señala?
¿Tiene un único identificador?

Después el número de la respuesta (¿A quien señala? = 3 tablas) Me indica que la relación por lo menos es uno a 3 o varios, si no la quieres limitar.

Bueno, es una pequeña idea de como resuelvo este dilema.

Answer (score 2):

Dados los tres tipos de relaciones destacadas, las mismas se utilizan teóricamente para relacionar los datos entre ellos.

Estas relaciones teóricas (por que en la practica tienen que estar forzadas por reglas), se utilizan para entender mejor la relación entre los datos.

Los datos se relacionan según la cardinalidad de los mismos. Por lo tanto un dato con una cardinalidad 1:1 significa que por cada dato de la tabla A existe una relación única e inequívoca con un dato de la tabla B.

En una relación 1:muchos, significa que por cada dato de la tabla A existirá 0 o mas datos en la tabla B.

En una relación muchos a muchos, la cardinalidad va de 0 a infinito para las dos tablas. Sin embargo, existe una tabla padre que fuerza siempre la relación para que aparezcan datos en la otra tabla.

Todo esto es teoría. Y uno podría forzar otras formas de relacionar los datos. Podría existir una relación 1:11, forzada por el sistema, que impida que haya mas de 11 elementos para la tabla B, siendo uno solo A (tal vez, la formación de un equipo de futbol).

Answer (score 2):

**Especificación Técnica**

> La *cardinalidad de una relación* es el ratio de ocurrencias de datos
>   entre dos tablas A y B.

Estas pueden ser de tres tipos:

- **1 a 1** : Se aplicarán relaciones 1:1 entre dos entidades cuando tan sólo pueda existir un elemento B por cada elemento en A.
- **1 a muchos** : Se aplicarán relaciones 1:N cuando puedan existir más de un elemento en B para cada elemento en A.
- **Muchos a Muchos** : Se aplicaran realiciones N:M cuando muchos elementos en B se relacionen con muchos elementos de A.

**Contextualización de las reglas en ejemplos prácticos**

Para explicar estas reglas, pongamos como ejemplo una compañia que quiere modelar las relaciones entre sus EMPLEADOS, RESPONSABLES, EQUIPOS y PROYECTOS:

- Un EMPLEADO tan sólo podría pertenece a un EQUIPO (1:1)
- Un EQUIPO tan sólo puede tener un RESPONSABLE (1:1)
- Un EQUIPO puede tener más de un EMPLEADO (1:N)
- Un EMPLEADO puede trabajar en más de un PROYECTO y a su vez, un PROYECTO puede tener varios EMPLEADOS (N:M)
- UN PROYECTO tan sólo puede tener un RESPONSABLE (1:1)

Este es un ejemplo de esta compañía ficticia y es obvio que este modelo no será valido para todas.

Espero que esto te ayude.

Un saludo